# how does c++ compiler handle "this" pointer in virtual function

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, this-pointer

i got a confuse about how does c++ compiler handle "this" pointer in virtual function, my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;



class A {
        public:
                void print_A(void) {
                        cout << "A::THIS = " << this << endl;

                        return;
                }

                int a;

        virtual ~A(void) {
                return;
        }
};

class B {
        public:
                virtual void print(void) {
                        cout << "B::THIS = " << this << endl;

                        return;
                }

                int b;
};

class C: public A, public B {
        public:
                void print(void) {
                        cout << "C::THIS = " << this << endl;

                        return;
                }

                int c;
};


class D {
        public:

                int d;

                virtual ~D(void) {
                        return;
                }
};


class E: public D, public C {
        public:
                int e;

                virtual ~E(void) {
                        return;
                }
};

void global_print(B *pb) {
        cout << "pb = " << pb << endl;
        pb->print();

        return;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

        E e;
        A *pa = &e;
        B *pb = &e;
        C *pc = &e;
        D *pd = &e;
        E *pe = &e;


        cout << "pa = " << pa << endl;
        cout << "pb = " << pb << endl;
        cout << "pc = " << pc << endl;
        cout << "pd = " << pd << endl;
        cout << "pe = " << pe << endl;

        pb->print();
        pc->print();
        pe->print();


        global_print(&e);
        return 0;
```

this is result compiled with g++ in my linux:

```
pa = 0x7ffc1e7c7a80
pb = 0x7ffc1e7c7a90
pc = 0x7ffc1e7c7a80
pd = 0x7ffc1e7c7a70
pe = 0x7ffc1e7c7a70
C::THIS = 0x7ffc1e7c7a80
C::THIS = 0x7ffc1e7c7a80
C::THIS = 0x7ffc1e7c7a80
pb = 0x7ffc1e7c7a90
C::THIS = 0x7ffc1e7c7a80
```

I can't understand that i send `&e` to `global_print` and `pb` in `global_print` is equal to `0x7ffc1e7c7a90`. And then i invode `pb->print()`, the `this pointer` in `global_print` is `0x7ffc1e7c7a80` which is equel to `pc`. It seems that the `pb->print()` convert class B to class C, but class B is the father class of class C, how dose it convert?

And although pb can get addres of `C::print` by virtual function, it's only a address that havn't enough information to konw that is need to convert class B to class C, so how does the program konw that need to convert class B to class C in the run time?

THANKS a lot! wish have a nice day!

Comment: all non-static member functions have an implicit parameter which is the object theyre being called on, thats where this comes from

Comment: but pb in global_print() is a pointor that it can point to any derive object,  it means that pb need to convert to any type of derive class, but how dose pb konw which one it need to convert in the runtime?

Comment: The compiler does not convert a class (what would that ever mean?) It converts a pointer. Since the virtual function belongs to C, the compiler knows that this B pointer actually points to a base of C and not to a standalone B object.

Comment: i think the compiler doesn't know which derive object the pb point at actually in global_print(). so the class B convert to class C wouldn't happen in the compile time, it should happen in the program run time.but i don't konw how dose the program konw the class B should convert to class C?

Comment: Google "c++ adjustor thunk" to find relevant articles.  [Example hit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk#Object-oriented_programming)

Comment: Yes it happens at run time of course. The program knows to convert a B pointer to a C pointer the same way it knows to call a C function using a B pointer.

Comment: thanks guy, you show me a way

Comment: the program konws to call a C function using a B pointer by virtual function, i think the virtual table is only store the address of function, without the class of function. so we can get the address of C function but can't get the class of C function

Comment: One question per stackoverflow.com question, please. You are asking multiple questions about how virtual functions work.

Comment: What a virtual function table stores, and whether it exists at all, is an implementation detail. In a typical implementation, the virtual function table stores not only the function address, but also some data and/or code needed to convert pointers (exactly what is required to convert from B to C).

Comment: thanks @n. 'pronouns' m., you figure out my problem, best wishes to you